# Pinch and Zoom on BB Maps

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to find out some way to implement pinch and zoom feature on BlackBerry Maps. 
I am using MapField control to implement this feature. 
Has someone done that before or have an idea out to implement that on blackberry...?

Waiting for the reply.
Thanks